# Is it necessary to call base.OnAttached() in a WPF/Silverlight behavior?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, behavior

When deriving from `Behavior<T>`, most code samples explicitly call `base.OnAttached()` (and `base.OnDetaching()`) in the overridden methods. Is this necessary, or just 'good practice'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling base.OnAttached() and base.OnDetaching() in derived class does nothing, as those methods are empty in the Behavior base class.

For a more general explanation, this answer sums it up quite nicely : [When should you call base.Method() in overridden method, and how to mark this when you write code in team?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721541/when-should-you-call-base-method-in-overridden-method-and-how-to-mark-this-wh)

Comment: Thanks - I don't have access to Reflector so I have no idea what `Behavior` does internally. I can now sleep safely knowing that I am not subverting the class :)